# Javascript: Unable to iterate over getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying the following javascript code. it is taken directly from a w3school example but it is not working for some reason.

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
console.log(coll);
console.log(coll.length);

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

I printed the value of coll and coll.length in console to debug. Coll is coming to be htmlcollection of 10 items as expected. But coll.length is 0. Thats why code is not going inside the for loop.
If I force the code to go inside the loop by doing:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
```

I am getting following in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

Html code is below:

```
<button class=\"collapsible\">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class=\"content\"> <p>Lorem ipsum...</p> </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection, which means it can change while you run your code. So whatever you see with `console.log(coll)` is likely to happen _after_ your code has run. Try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(coll));` instead.

Comment: need to see your html as well

Comment: please share the html

Comment: shared html code.

Comment: @dgarg: please read my first comment carefully: your JS code runs **too early** (before those elements have been added to the DOM), hence you don't get the elements when it runs.

Comment: @zerkms I added console.log(JSON.stringify(coll)); and it is coming to be empty list. what is the solution to this.

Comment: @dgarg it depends. The simplest would be to run your JS **after** all your html.

Comment: I guess that if the code is put inside a function called in the `onLoad` attribute of the `body` element of the HTML, it will be able to access all the defined HTML.

Comment: As @zerkms  says, you have to use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {// do your stuff}` or put the script tag at the end of your page.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms. you analyzed the problem really well. I moved the script below the code and it working like a charm. New learning for me as I used to think that js code can be placed anywhere and browser loads the html before executing js.

Comment: @zerkms please add it as an answer so that I can select it

Comment: when i was in various stages of debug, i added a simple document.getElementById at the same place (before html) and it was working. why JS was able to see & work on that element

Comment: @dgarg just checkmark the Aryan's answer, they're good now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) returns a live HTML collection. That means that you need to create an array from that live HTML collection. For that, use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
<script>
var coll = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"));
var i;
console.log(coll);
console.log(coll.length);

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

## Edit

@zerkms is right about you needing to make sure the document is ready before running your code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var coll = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"));
  var i;
  console.log(coll);
  console.log(coll.length);

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight){
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 
    });
  }
})
</script>
```

You don't need that `Array.from` (I was wrong about that) but, hey, doesn't hurt.

Comment: You're almost there: they have a live collection, but it's empty. Empty live collection converted to an array is still just an empty array. Their problem is not "how", it's "**when**".

Answer (score -1):

BTW, If you wish to use `JQuery` then this can be achieved eaisly like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".collapsible", function () {
       this.classList.toggle("active");
       const content = this.nextElementSibling;
       if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = "";
       } else {
             content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
});
```

You don't need to read by class and loop around, this code will handle all of them

Comment: why is this downvoted? doesn't simple JQuery solves his problem?

Comment: JQuery is the lazy approach, the original poster is looking to learn not be lazy